# function to list directory an files doesnt work

Tags: unix

```
  1 #! /bin/bash
  2
  3
  4 a=$(ls $@)
  5 echo $a
  6 for var in $a
  7 do
  8   if [ -d $var ]
  9   then
  10   echo "$var is a directory"
  11   elif [ -f $var ]
  12   then
  13   echo "$var is a file"
  14   fi
  15 done
  16
```

the name of the script is test 2. If i type "sh test2 ." in shell it shows all files that are files and all directorys that are directorys in the current directory. However if I type in "sh test2 ~" in shell it doesnt show anything it just lists the files. Why does it not show the files and directorys in the home directory?

Comment: What do you mean *it doesnt show anything it just lists the files*?

Comment: as in it only computes line 5 and justs lists the contents of the directory(not files my mistake), it does not show which ones are files and which ones are directories.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the actual problem of your script. It's likely that `ls` is not giving an output that can be parsed. But here's a version you might want:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob  ## Prevents patterns from presenting themselves if no match is found.
shopt -s dotglob   ## Includes files stating with .
files=()
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    files=(*)
else
    for arg; do
        files+=("$arg"/*)
    done
fi
echo --------------------
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
echo --------------------
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ -d $file ]]; then
        echo "$file is a directory."
    elif [[ -f $file ]]; then
        echo "$file is a file."
    fi
done
echo --------------------
```